# HERE Fleet Telemetics API cannot find route when routing API has no issue?

Tags: here-api

Why is the fleet telematics API (needed because I need toll calculations) unable to find a route when the routing API is?

Fleet telematics request:
`https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=..&app_code=UB0aWrkozKtjf6brTv4byg&app_id=..=1&height=4.1148m&length=16.1544m&limitedWeight=80000lbs&maneuverattributes=direction%2Caction&maxSpeed=90mph&metricSystem=imperial&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&representation=display&return=polyline&routeattributes=waypoints%2Csummary%2Cshape%2Clegs%2CspeedProfile&shippedHazardousGoods=&speedProfile=fast&tollVehicleType=truck&vehicleWeight=80000lbs&waypoint0=geo%2130.1353066%2C-97.8301877%3B200&waypoint1=geo%2130.2804572%2C-97.7250785%3B200`

Routing request:
`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.17.0&apikey=...&apiKey=...&detail=1&height=4.1148&length=16.1544&limitedWeight=40&maneuverattributes=direction%2Caction&metricSystem=imperial&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&representation=display&return=polyline&routeattributes=waypoints%2Csummary%2Cshape%2Clegs&shippedHazardousGoods=&tollVehicleType=truck&vehicleWeight=40&waypoint0=geo!30.1353066%2C-97.8301877%3B200&waypoint1=geo!30.2804572%2C-97.7250785%3B200`

Fleet telematics response (failed):
`{"issues":[{"message":"Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links -716069232 716069232  dest links -1240081052 -1240081051 -766146364 -766146023 -766146022 -766146021 -766146020 -766146019 -766146018 -766146017 -766146016 -766146015 -766146014 -766146012 -766146011 -766146010 -764262013 -761659546 -761601143 -761601142 -761601136 -761601135 -761601131 -761601129 -761601127 -761601124 -761601123 -761601122 -761601121 -761601120 -761587486 -761587485 -761587482 -761587479 -761587478 -761587477 -761587452 -761587451 -18143390 -18143161 -18143160 -18143099 -18143058 -18143035 18143035 18143058 18143099 18143160 18143161 18143390 761587451 761587452 761587477 761587478 761587479 761587482 761587485 761587486 761601120 761601121 761601122 761601123 761601124 761601127 761601129 761601131 761601135 761601136 761601142 761601143 761659546 764262013 766146010 766146011 766146012 766146014 766146015 766146016 766146017 766146018 766146019 766146020 766146021 766146022 766146023 766146364 1240081051 1240081052 ), closest link to destination reached: 716069232 at 30.13952/-97.8306, issues: illegal access, length"},{"message":"Request id: 261242ac-f71d-44c0-8484-a352d2e5ac79"}],"error_id":"261242ac-f71d-44c0-8484-a352d2e5ac79","response_code":"400 Bad Request"}`

The Fleet API returns an error with issue: `issues: illegal access, length`.

This is weird because both lengths are the same, as are both waypoints.

Is Fleet API not respecting the geo radius of 200m provided?
Should I just go back to use the TCE API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your Fleet Telematics request, you were using some of the Routing API parameters that are not supported by the Fleet Telematics API.
For instance, &metricSystem=imperial, &representation=display, &speedProfile=fast, are not supported. Also, for waypoints, geo! option is also not supported currently.
Please check the document [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html) for reference.

Interesting enough, by removing the extra parameters with below API call, still no route found.
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?&apiKey=[YOUR API KEY]&height=4.1148m&length=16.1544m&limitedWeight=80000lbs&maneuverattributes=direction%2Caction&maxSpeed=90mph&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&return=polyline&routeattributes=waypoints%2Csummary%2Cshape%2Clegs%2CspeedProfile&tollVehicleType=truck&vehicleWeight=80000lbs&waypoint0=30.1353066,-97.8301877;200&waypoint1=30.2804572,-97.7250785;200

After checking more, it seems the value of "length=16.1544m" caused the problem. By reduce the length to 13m, a route can be found.

So, it could be a fleet api issue. Let us check with our development team, and feedback here later.

Comment: Thanks! Any update with the dev team? This length is an issue for almost all routes, when it works fine for the routing api.

Comment: Fleet Telematic API dev team is actively checking on the issue. The fix is planned to be done in the coming 2 weeks. We will keep you posted for the release plan when available.

Comment: Hi Here team, really appreciate the updates. Is the fix scheduled for release yet?

Comment: The fix seems taking more effort than expected. The dev team is still working on the fix. Will let you know when there is more update on this.

Comment: Hi, any updates? This is a large issues preventing much of our routing from working and we would hate to have to switch providers over this

Answer (score 0):

For fleet just add one more parameter: &trailerType=2 .

Then fleet request is like that:
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=..&app_code=UB0aWrkozKtjf6brTv4byg&app_id=..=1&height=4.1148m&length=16.1544m&limitedWeight=80000lbs&maneuverattributes=direction%2Caction&maxSpeed=90mph&metricSystem=imperial&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&representation=display&return=polyline&routeattributes=waypoints%2Csummary%2Cshape%2Clegs%2CspeedProfile&shippedHazardousGoods=&speedProfile=fast&tollVehicleType=truck&vehicleWeight=80000lbs&waypoint0=geo%2130.1353066%2C-97.8301877%3B200&waypoint1=geo%2130.2804572%2C-97.7250785%3B200&trailerType=2

Now it works like a charm.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tyler2P it is **not** link only, it is an example URL

Comment: Hi, @Tyler2P thanks for your comment and suggestion. I'm new here, next time I'll do it more clearly..
But as Someone_who_likes_SE said. 
At the first line I put te essential part of the answer. "For fleet just add one more parameter: &trailerType=2". Link is just an example.